# Time Limit issue in mod_multicast ejabberd

Tags: multicast, ejabberd, mod-multicast

**We are using [mod_multicast](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/blob/2.1.x/mod_multicast/src/mod_multicast.erl) with ejabberd 2.1.11 with the following configuration**

```
[{host, "multicast.server_ip"},
 {access, multicast},
 {limits,
  [{local, message, infinite},
   {local, presence, infinite},
   {remote, message, infinite}]}]
```

**but we are getting this error in response when we send a second broadcast message after two three seconds of first message,**

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="multicast.server_ip" to="8_9414440765@server_ip/10909448101435316508474960" type="error" id="1435316983">
<addresses xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/address">
<address type="to" desc="1435316983" jid="10_9414756966@server_ip"/>
<address type="cc" desc="1435316983" jid="9_8386837120@server_ip"/>
</addresses><ftype>emoji</ftype>
<body>[FG#007]</body>
<broadcastid>6</broadcastid>
<error code="403" type="auth">
<forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
<text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">
Packet relay is denied by service policy</text></error></message>
```

**When we are sending a message after some time, it goes well.**

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd 2.1.11 is more than 3 years old and is not supported anymore. My suggestion for first step is to switch to a more up to date ejabberd, like ejabberd 15.06.